# Image not showing with codeigniter framework but the complete link is shown when the page is rendered

Tags: php, image, codeigniter

I am kind of a novice with codeigniter but this seems odd all the same. When the page is rendered the complete and correct link to the image is seen and if you click on it in firebug it opens up the image.

```
<?php
$content = <<<ENDHTML
<img class="banner" href="
ENDHTML;
$imgUrl = asset_Url().'images/logo.png';
$content1 = <<<ENDHTML
" alt="Company Logo"><h1 class="banner">MyWebApp</h1>
ENDHTML;
echo $content.$imgUrl.$content1;
?>
```

The rendered code looks like this

```
<img class="banner" href="http://localhost/myWebAppFolder/assets/images/logo.png" alt="Company Logo"><h1 class="banner">MyWebApp</h1>           <!-- Header Section -->
```

I read one of the previous answers about asset locations with codeigniter and I have made my own asset helper file, which works fine for the CSS and JavaScript but not for the images. Please help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `href` to specify the image URL when the image tag uses the `src` attribute.

Try changing to:

```
$content = <<<ENDHTML
<img class="banner" src="
ENDHTML;
$imgUrl = asset_Url().'images/logo.png';
$content1 = <<<ENDHTML
" alt="Company Logo"><h1 class="banner">MyWebApp</h1>
ENDHTML;
echo $content.$imgUrl.$content1;
```

This would render:

```
<img class="banner" src="http://localhost/...
```

which would be correct and should work.